# Rounding numpy float array read from img with python, values returned not rounded

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Simple rounding of a floating point numpy array seems not working for some reason..

I get numpy array from reading a huge img (shape of (7352, 7472)). Ex values:

```
>>> imarray[3500:3503, 5000:5003]
array([[ 73.33999634,  73.40000153,  73.45999908],
       [ 73.30999756,  73.37999725,  73.43000031],
       [ 73.30000305,  73.36000061,  73.41000366]], dtype=float32)
```

And for rounding I've been just trying to use numpy.around() for the raw value, also writing values to a new array, a copie of raw array, but for some reason no results..

```
arr=imarray
numpy.around(imarray, decimals=3, out=arr)
arr[3500,5000] #results in 73.3399963379, as well as accessing imarray
```

So, even higher precision!!!
Is that because of such big array?

I need to round it to get the most frequent value (mode), and I'm searching the vay to avoid more and more libraries..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array has dtype `float32`. That is a 4-byte float.
The closest float to 73.340 representable using `float32` is roughly 73.33999634:

```
In [62]: x = np.array([73.33999634, 73.340], dtype = np.float32)

In [63]: x
Out[63]: array([ 73.33999634,  73.33999634], dtype=float32)
```

So I think `np.around` is rounding correctly, it is just that your `dtype` has too large a granularity to round to the number you might be expecting.

```
In [60]: y = np.around(x, decimals = 3)

In [61]: y
Out[61]: array([ 73.33999634,  73.33999634], dtype=float32)
```

Whereas, if the dtype were `np.float64`:

```
In [64]: x = np.array([73.33999634, 73.340], dtype = np.float64)

In [65]: y = np.around(x, decimals = 3)

In [66]: y
Out[66]: array([ 73.34,  73.34])
```

Note that even though printed representation for `y` shows 73.34, it is not necessarily true that the real number 73.34 is exactly representable as a float64 either. The float64 representation is probably just so close to 73.34 that NumPy chooses to print it as 73.34.

Comment: But isn't then that double float should have even bigger granularity?

Comment: A `float64` is an 8-byte float. So it can represent more numbers than a `float32`. More numbers means smaller granularity.

Comment: yeah, I meant finer or great (and bigger is always greater:)) granularity.. (Language pecularities)..   But then in any case I suppose float64 is better. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @unutbu is absolutely correct.  Numpy is rounding it as close to the number as it can given the precision that you requested.  The only thing that I have to add is that you can use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to change how the array is displayed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([73.33999634, 73.340], dtype = np.float32)
>>> y = np.round(x, decimals = 3)
>>> y
array([ 73.33999634,  73.33999634], dtype=float32)
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
>>> y
array([ 73.34,  73.34], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Cool, didn't hear about this!
But this does not change the input data, which I intend to do..